# PHP Erasing from .txt file last line makes a new line

Tags: php

Hi I'm creating an WordPress plugin which will add comments automatically.
To make it easier for agency I'd want to implement comments from .txt file.

And basically script is looking like that

```
$comments_file = 'komentarze.txt';
$comments_file2 = fopen("komentarze.txt", "r") or die ("Can't open the file.");

//COUNT LINES
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($comments_file, "r");

while(!feof($handle)){
    $line = fgets($handle);
    $linecount++;
}

fclose($handle);

//SHOW RANDOM LINE
$lines = file($comments_file); //change file into array
if($linecount == 1) {
    $randomize = rand(0,count(file($comments_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)));
} else {
    $randomize = rand(0, count(file($comments_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES))-1);
}
$rand_comment = $lines[$randomize]; //random comment
echo "<br> Adding comment: " . $randomize;


// * DELETING COMMENT FROM FILE
$contents = file_get_contents($comments_file);
$contents = str_replace($rand_comment, '', $contents);
//preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $contents);
file_put_contents($comments_file, $contents);

echo "<br> File contains ". ($linecount-1). " comments.";

echo "<div class='mt-3 border shadow-sm rounded p-3 overflow-auto' style='height: 300px;'>";
// * SHOW ALL LINES
$i = 0;
while(!feof($comments_file2)) {
    echo "<p>" . $i++ . ". " . fgets($comments_file2) . "</p>";
}

echo "</div>";

echo "<p class='mt-4 text-muted'>Preview comment:</p>";
echo '<blockquote class="blockquote border rounded bg-light shadow p-3">
                <p class="mb-0">'.$rand_comment.'</p>
                <footer class="pt-2 blockquote-footer">Kinomaniak '.$names[$random_name[1]].'</footer>
            </blockquote>';

//echo "<p class=\"text-danger\">Rolled comment number <b></b>.";
echo "<p class=''>Comment above was added and deleted from file</p>";
echo "<p class=\"\">ATM in file there are ". $linecount - 1 ." comments.";

?>
```

Yeah and the main issue with this code is that it's adding on the end of file empty line if the last line is going to be added and deleted.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crCrL.png)

Does anyone know how to fix it or what is causing this issue?

Comment: I would recommend to initially store the return of file in an array, remove/add what you need and use file_put_contents(implode("\n", $lines)); You should also avoid multiple file() calls when you have you $lines array.

Comment: What @DB said. Plus, you are not only reading the file contents with `file()` multiple times, before that you are already reading it in yet another way, doing fopen + fgets in a loop + fclose - apparently for little other reason, than to determine the number of lines? That you could have had by simply count()-ing the elements you got in your array _after_ you called `file()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll repair it with your advices.